# How to schedule a job for every 2:30 hours between 1:00 AM and 5:00 AM using quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule a job for every 2:30 hours between 1:00 AM and 5:00 AM using only single cron expression. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

according to my understanding of your question. just try this

0 150 1-5 ? * * *

for more information you can take help of following link. may be this helps you.

http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/cron-expression-ever-hours/

Answer (score 0):

I am modifying answer please check with this. may be this is correct but not sure. just try

0 30 2 1-5 * * *